# Kendo UI Autocomplete returns empty value if a text string contains the word "null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the Kendo UI Autocomplete widget on a project in order to locate a specific location for a customer, but got an error I can't seem to find a suitable answer for.

The model in my DataSource is pretty simple and consists of 4 properties - Name, Address, City, and an interlacement of them all. Fx "Michael Johnson, Bowing Street, NY".

The option for my widget is following:

```
<input id="deliveryAddress" name="deliveryAddress"                                      
   kendo-auto-complete
   k-ng-model="vm.currentAddress"
   k-data-source="vm.searchAddresses"
   k-data-value-field="'id'"
   k-data-text-field="'nameAndFullAddress'"
   k-min-length="2"/>
```

The problem is I have an entry in my collection, where the sentence "null" occours in - "Knullen". When I try to select this specific entry in my widget, the selected value is somehow an empty array. Notice that the "null" sentence occours in the k-data-text-field. If you remove a single L from the sentence, it works as intended and you can get the selected value.

I've created a Dojo:
http://dojo.telerik.com/EsAHA

Anyone have an explanation for this or seen something similar?

Comment: This is such a wierd behaviour actually. You should post in telerik forum as it seems to be - at least to me - an internal bug. It doesn't thrown any exception in console and in fact it shouldn't, as it should be treated as a string and *null*  should not be evaluated.

Comment: Yes, Really it's a strange behavior from kendo, you should post in telerik.

If you are stuck in something then you can use this one 

http://dojo.telerik.com/EsAHA/7

you will get all the properties of selected item. check console to see.

Hope it will solve your problem on temporary basis. :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. :) I'll forward it to Telerik.

Comment: This bug Is fixed on the Kendo UI 2019 R2